# How get checkbox object from listview in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'd like to make checkboxlistview in wpf application like this image

[image: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mystorage-ded50.appspot.com/o/checkbox_wpf.PNG?alt=media&token=66455dea-f56e-4373-af93-b62730501aec])
If I check any item on left listview the items of right one should be checked.
I can't use binding, because It's shared project and I need to add UWP project after finish WPF project.
So I can't make binding items to VeiwModel for this project.
I'd like to catch the click event of left items and set the check property to right items. But I can get the checkbox objects from the right listview.

```
void OnCheckboxClicked1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
    var id = checkBox.Tag;
    CheckSubList(checkBox.IsChecked, id.ToString());
}

void OnCheckboxClicked2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
void CheckSubList(bool? isChecked, string Id)
{

    foreach (object listView in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(rightListView as FrameworkElement))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OKOK");
        //foreach (object checkbox in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj as FrameworkElement))
        //{
        //    // Some code
        //}
    }
}
```

If anyone have a good idea, please help me. Thanks

Comment: Take a look here http://www.licensespot.com/blog/wpf-listview-checkbox

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, did you check my code I want to get checkbox object in CheckSubList method.
But the the code seems to use click event and binding.

Comment: Post your XAML please

Comment: This is xaml file [here](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mystorage-ded50.appspot.com/o/Xaml.txt?alt=media&token=aacf34bc-0cd3-482d-aa5e-9fedc2436863)